# SQL filter by Subquery

Tags: sql, filter, subquery

I have the following Table:

```
ID      WBSTK   
77807   C  
77808   C  
80345   A  
80383   A  
80989   A  
85997   C  
91212   A  
91397   A
```

and my desired outcome is:

```
ID      WBSTK   
80345   A  
80383   A  
80989   A
```

So I want to get as a result all "A"s which have a smaller ID than any "C".
I tried something like that, but I couldn't get it work:

```
    SELECT   vbuk1.ID,  vbuk1.WBSTK,  vbuk2.ID
    FROM t1 vbuk1 
         LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID,  WBSTK 
         FROM t1 WHERE WBSTK='C'  ) vbuk2 ON vbuk1.ID=vbuk2.ID
    WHERE vbuk1.ID<=vbuk2.ID
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: below answers were based on your original question and people invested time to answer.

Comment: I am sorry. As you can see I'm new to StackOverflow, so I'm not really aware about the procedures and the do's / don'ts on this site. 
I understood now better. Thanks for your answer! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with a subquery

You can filter with a correlated subquery

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where 
    wbstk = 'A'
    and id < (select max(id) from mytable where wbstk = 'C')
```

Or you can build upon your join strategy:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
inner join (select max(id) id from mytable where wbstk = 'C') d
    on t.id < d.id
where wbstk = 'A'
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6a093fa0f0a65da36f1a1bd15df40007)**

```
   id | wbstk
----: | :----
80345 | A    
80383 | A    
80989 | A
```

Comment: thank you. Because of my enhancement described under EDIT, I think it's not possible to work with MAX statement.

Comment: @David . . . You had already accepted this answer, presumably because it answered your original question.  I would suggest that you undo the edits on your question, re-accept this answer, and then ask a new question.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I'm new to S.O. so I'm not really aware about the procedures and the do's / don'ts on this site. 
I understood now better. Thanks for your hint, I will follow that!

Answer (score 1):

Here's your query.

```
select  t1.ID, t1.WBSTK
from vbuk1 t1
inner join vbuk1 t2 on t2.ID > t1.ID and t2.WBSTK='C' 
where t1.WBSTK='A'
```

see [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=PqFvfCQ7r9)

Answer (score 0):

In most databases, you can do:

```
select t.* 
from t
where t.id < all (select t2.id from t t2 where t2.WBSTK = 'C') and
      t.WBSTK = 'A';
```

This is handy because it will return all As even when there are no Cs.

EDIT:

If you actually want to not see any As if there a no Cs, then just use aggregation in the subquery:

```
select t.* 
from t
where t.id < (select max(t2.id) from t t2 where t2.WBSTK = 'C') and
      t.WBSTK = 'A';
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. But this is what I want to avoid. As written, I want to see only the As which have a smaller ID than any C

Comment: @David . . . What are you trying to avoid?  This seems to answer your question.

Comment: If there are no such Cs bigger than an A, I don't want to see any As.

Comment: @David . . . The query is easily adjusted for that.

Comment: thank you @Gordon!
Did you see my EDIT?
Do you know if It's possible to compare with the MAX ID on group level?